# what's the difference between 'git stash apply stash@{2}' and 'git stash apply --2'

Tags: git

say i have a git stash list like below:

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: 049d078 added the index file
stash@{1}: WIP on master: c264051 Revert "added file_size"
stash@{2}: WIP on master: 21d80a5 added number to log
```

what's the difference between `git stash apply stash@{2}` and `git stash apply --2' when I type this two command respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recognize that `--2` syntax, and I'm not sure Git does either.  It seems that `git stash apply --2` does the same thing as `git stash apply`, i.e. it applies the most recent stash.